# How can I draw a railway route on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code:

```js
function trainRoute(startPoint, endPoint) {
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({ strokeColor: '#af1a1a', strokeWeight: 2 });
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions: polyline, suppressMarkers: true });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var request = {
        origin: startPoint,
        destination: endPoint,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT 
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Using `travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING` I see the line, but it is not what I'm looking for. I think I need `.TRANSIT` with some more options, like `VehicleType.RAIL`.

I don't know how to do it! I've tried on searching on Google, but couldn't find anything!

---

I think this is the right way to do this :

```
var request = {
    origin: puntoPartenza,
    destination: puntoArrivo,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
            var steps = legs[i].steps;
            for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                var transitMode = steps[j].travel_mode;

                if (transitMode == "TRANSIT") {
                    var vehicle = steps[j].transit.line.vehicle.type;
                    if (vehicle == "HEAVY_RAIL") {
                        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        }                            
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
});
```

but :

1) why it draw only a part of route?

2) on the returned JSON object of DirectionsStatus, there are also info about walking and/or TRANSIT. So what's the meaning of `travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT` ?!?!?

but I get `TypeError: google.maps.TransitVehicle is undefined`

Comment: You might find some helpful examples here at the directions service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes Though I am wondering if the TRANSIT support in the API is possible to specify down to the RAIL level (as opposed to bus or "funicular") - they just recently added Transit Directions support to the API (source: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/public-transit-routing-and-layer-now.html)

Comment: There is no example with RAIL or BUS :(

Comment: You might have to rethink how the Google Maps API allows you to tap into it's Public Transit layer. Do you have documentation to show that it offers those options on the Transit layer? My guess is that it might not, currently. For context here is an explanation (a while back) on why they have such difficulty offering Transit routes for developers (as opposed to walking or driving, which does not require licensing data from a large number of public transit organizations around the world): http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=713#c76

Comment: But there are the API support : I believe I can draw a railway line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just make up syntax and expect it to work [Transit VehicleType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#VehicleType) does include RAIL, but [TransitVehicle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TransitVehicle), doesn't have a vehicle property.

There is no property vehicle in Transit vehicle.  Look at the "type" property.

Comment: It is the same! I get the same error! I'm making some properties in the wrong place, but Google API are not clear at all here :(

Comment: I mean : vehicle: google.maps.VehicleType.RAIL fail. I think I need to put transitLine options elsewhere, right? Any idea?

Comment: I just realized that the infos are stored on DirectionsResult object. So I need to draw polyline due to this specific! Tried somethings like `steps[j].transit.line.vehicle.type;` , but it is not clear at all how to filter the infor with this :O

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, it worked for me,

```
var directionsServiceRequest = {
                    destination: {lat: 39.79, lng: -86.14},
                    origin: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65},
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
                    transitOptions: {modes:['TRAIN']}
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this in the documentation-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TransitVehicle.

It is probably .TRAIN and not .RAIL

Comment: No! It's a configuration fault, I don't know where to place that code...ghghgh